# get error with just a 'public' at delphi TForm class

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, tform

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  Button1:TButton;
  Memo1:TMemo;
end;
```

that's normal code about delphi form.

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  public
    Button1:TButton;
    Memo1:TMemo;
end;
```

just add a public keyword.

get a runtime error.

i am very confused about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't specify visibility then members are `published` which means they are `public` and get RTTI (Run Time Type Information) generated for them. The RTTI is needed for the form streaming to work. By making them `public` you are removing the RTTI so things will fail.